# Browsing an apps folder structure on an iDevice

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes

When I plug my iPhone into the computer can I access an apps folder structure that's on the phone? Either programatically or manually with a tool that doesn't involve jailbreaking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It cant be done without jailbreaking, you basically must create your app folder structure with xcode.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [iExplorer](http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/)? See if that satisfies your requirements.(It doesn't need the device to be jailbroken).